# CXF to generate strings instead of enums

Tags: java, jaxb, cxf, xjc, cxf-xjc-plugin

I have for example a WSDL definition construct like this:

```
     <xsd:simpleType name="MyDayType">
        <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
           <xsd:enumeration value="Sat"/>
           <xsd:enumeration value="Wed"/>
        </xsd:restriction>
     </xsd:simpleType>
```

And then you have some other object with for example:

```
     <xsd:complexType name="MyEntity">
        <xsd:sequence>
           <xsd:element name="dayType" type="v:MyDayType" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
        </xsd:sequence>
     </xsd:complexType>
```

Now if I use the cxf-codegen-plugin, it will generate an enum "MyDayType" and references it in the "MyEntity" class. Usually this is exactly what you want.

However in my case I cannot use the enum as I am restricted in the way the generated Java code is used later on. So I would like that CXF generate strings instead of enums. So it simply maps all occurrence of this type in other objects to a string.
In my example instead of:

```
public class MyEntity {
  protected List<MyEntity> dayType;
  /** Getters(/Setters) **/
}
```

I would like to have:

```
public class MyEntity {
  protected List<String> dayType;
  /** Getters(/Setters) **/
}
```

How can I achieve this?
I would rather prefer some way of doing that without writing my own custom jaxb plugin.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to cheat myself to what I want.
There is a config where you can set a value how much is the longest parameter name for an enum. If the enum contains value's that exceed this value, CXF will generate strings instead of enums.

I simply set this value to 1, so that every enum is bigger then the limit.

There is a description on how to set the value here: 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/12779608/1448704